# Why should I use multiple origins for a cloudfront distribution?

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

I understand, that I get a new domain for my distribution, but why would i need multiple origins for one distribution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A scenario could be a single CloudFront distribution for `example.com` with multiple sub-applications (origins) that come together to create a single application:

- Static website at / (S3 configured as static website endpoint)
- Blog at /blog path (ALB)
- API at /api path (API Gateway)
- Static assets at /static path (S3 bucket)